# Taking input from one class and used in present class

Tags: inheritance, package

I want to write two programs in same package.On this package the 1st class has only input data is present.And the 2nd class taken this input from 1st class and all the methods on the 2nd class is used this input.

For example:

```
Package ex;
    class A{
     public static void main(String args[]){
        int a,b,c;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a value:");
        a=s.next();
        System.out.println("Enter b value:");
        b=s.next();
      }   
    }
    class B extends A{
        void Add(){
         c=a+b;
         System.out.println(C);
         }
        void Sub(){
          c=a-b;
          System.out.println(c);
    }    
    }
```

---

### **Now creating Another package and am importing this package also:**

```
 Package ex2;
    import ex.A;
    class Addition{
        public static void main(String args[]){
           A aa = new A();
           aa.add();
        }
    }
```

---

On package ex we have two classes, 1st class contains input and 2nd class contain methods.
On package ex2, we are importing package ex and creating one object, by using this object am accessing the methods. This is not working.
I just tried and i know this is not the procedure. can u please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got the solution. It was the exact solution. But the lines of code is high. I  will think in another way.can you guys help me is there any logic for this

```
package org.maths;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputData {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int x,y;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter A:");
        x=s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter B:");
        y=s.nextInt();
        Methods mm = new Methods();
        mm.add(x, y);
        mm.sub(x, y);
    }

}

package org.maths;

public class Methods extends InputData {

    int z;
    public void add(int x, int y){
        z=x+y;
        System.out.println("Addition of two numbers:"+" "+z);
    }
    public void sub(int x, int y){
        z=x-y;
        System.out.println("Substarction of two numbers:"+" "+z);
    }

}


 package org.ex;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import org.maths.*;
    public class Ex1 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //System.out.println("Akhil");
            int x,y;
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("A");
            x=s.nextInt();
            System.out.println("B");
            y=s.nextInt();
            Methods m = new Methods();
            m.add(x, y);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you do not need to have two main functions, you need to have just one starting point for the JVM which the one in your addition class can serve.
Then pass those integers a,b,and c to the A class or class B that extends it. 
You can read more about java constructor here:
[Java Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

So that your A class will be something like:

```
class A{
int a,b,c;
public A(int a,int b,int c)
{
this.a = a;
this.b = b;
this.c = c;
}
}

class B extends A
{
public B(int a, int b,int c)
{
super(a,b,c);
}
void Add(){
this.c=this.a+this.b;
System.out.println(this.c);
}
void Sub(){
this.c=this.a-this.b;
System.out.println(this.c);
}
```

Then you can call the Addition class as you did above. It it in the Addition class the you will call the Scanner methods to get the inputs for a, and b.